# Encrypt and decrypt the hidden input values in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, encryption

How to encrypt the Hidden input value in Laravel blade and Decrypt it while storing in database (Controller).while edit how to pass the  vale with input encrypt

```
<form action="/action_page.php">

  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br><br>
  <input type="hidden" id="custId" name="custId" value="3487">
  <input type="hidden" id="custId" name="custId" value="{{$input->id}}">
   <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

here encrypt  type is not in url .Its for for Hidden input field.how  we can do this in Laravel 8 . all values passing to ajax to controller?.while inspect the page means its showing hidden input values .

Answer (score 1):

You can use this

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/encryption

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Encryption\DecryptException;
//for encrypt 
$encrypted = Crypt::encryptString($value)
//for decrypt
try {
$decrypted = Crypt::decryptString($encryptedValue);} catch (DecryptException $e) { //}
```

Comment: but when we inspect the page means the hidden input value is visible does abouve method can we use in blade file ?